# C++. Why std::cout << char + int prints int value?

Tags: c++, std, cout

Let's say, we have:

```
char x = 'a';
int y = 1;
```

So, if you run:

```
std::cout << x + y;
```

It prints 98 instead of 'b'. As i see from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) 
`<<operator` has only **int** parameter implementation.

From now on i have 2 questions:

1. After **char + int** operation what type is returned?
2. Why there is no **char** parameter implementation, but `std::cout << x` still works as expected and prints **char** value?

Comment: Read this : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion (Section Numeric promotions -> Integral promotion)

Comment: 2) There is another set of  [non-member operator<<](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/) that also works with the stream.

Comment: And this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2 for the implementation of `operator<<` for `char`. You should forget cplusplus.com, it's not a very comprehensive website.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [Fefux](/users/7131047/), [Bo Persson](/users/597607/) and [Matti Virkkunen](/users/227267/) answers are:

1. From [CPP Reference: Implicit conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

   > arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than `int` as
   >   arguments, and integral promotions are automatically applied after
   >   lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable.

   So return type of `x + y` is **`int`**.
2. `std::cout` has a `operator<<(char)` as a [non-member](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/).

Answer (score -3):

As you probably know, C++ is backward compatible with C.

Both C & C++ treat `char`s like `int`s.

You may consider this a flaw of the language, but on the contrary, this is very handy.

Suppose you want to convert a capital letter to the corresponding small letter. Since any capital letter has an ASCII code 32 below the corresponding small letter, this is as simple as this:

```
char c = 'A';

std::cout << (char) (c + 32); // output: 'a'
```

Inversely you can convert from small letter to capital letter:

```
char c = 'a';

std::cout << (char) (c - 32); // output: 'A'
```

Comment: "*As you probably know, C++ is backward compatible with C.*" Sadly that's not true.

Comment: @GillBates, almost true. And the "almost" is enough.

Comment: "almost" is not to be found anywhere in your answer.

Comment: @GillBates, do you want that I add the word "almost" to my answer? I think the OP is smart enough to understand where the "almost" applies.